# Change installed application's name

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

We have created an application which is installed using Innosetup.
Marketing have now decided to rebrand the application ("NewAppName"), so we are in the process of updating our installer for the rebranded app.
We can install the new app, but what we also want to do is uninstall any old versions ("OldAppName") of the app that may be installed (note. we only support 64bit).

What I need the Inno-Setup to do is:

1. Uninstall existing installations (NewAppName & OldAppName)
2. Perform new installation.

If I look at my personal installation, I can see that both installed apps are located in the same folder (not sure if can navigate to the OldApp uninstaller from the NewApp location):

```
C:\Program Files\MyCompany\OldAppName\unins000.exe (Uninstaller path)
C:\Program Files\MyCompany\NewAppName\unins000.exe (Uninstaller path)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by *"execute similar"*? Are you asking how to run your PowerShell script from Inno Setup? Or do you want to reimplement your PowerShell script in Inno Setup (Pascal Script)? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am wanting to see how to execute this using Inno-setup as I am not familiar with it, the installer was created by someone else. 
I managed to update the existing installer by changing the App name in the .iss file, but that is as far as my exposure to Inno-setup goes

Comment: Imo you keep using unnecessarily vague statements. Do I read *"execute this installation"* correctly as *"execute this PowerShell script"*? + When should the script execute? Before the actual installation? Or it does not matter?

Comment: My goal here is to:
1. Remove any existing installations (OldAppName or NewAppName). 
2. Perform installation of NewAppName

I dont mind if it is executing the Powershell script, or if it is a script written in Pascal, I just shared the Powershell script to show I tried something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With complex upgrades, sometimes the appropriate solution is to uninstall the existing package and then install the new version. This is the purpose of UninsIS.dll:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/UninsIS

It provides version comparison functionality and the ability to uninstall the existing installed version based on your application's requirements.